# why won't displacement map work in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, displacement

I'm using cycles as my render engine and usually when applying materials I just do it in the material preview tab and then assume that they work in cycles as well and usually this was the case.

I've got a material I got online that I'm trying to add to a pipe that I've modelled and I'm having some trouble, the effects of the displacement map won't show up when I try to get a test render in cycles, I tried increasing the scale of the map and that did nothing.

please help.

[Here's the file with the material maps packaged](https://workupload.com/file/jBz4J8KmqUG)

Comment: You haven't packed the images, but have you set your material correctly? In the Material panel > Settings > Displacement > choose Displacement Only or Displacement and Bump instead of Bump, and you need to give more geometry to your object, otherwise the Displacement can't displace anything, and to be in Rendered Preview to see the effect

Comment: the file is missing the image textures. You can go to File > External Data > Pack Ressources to add them to your file. And yup @moonboots got it, your material is set to "Bump only"

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the advice, I did try setting the material setting to bump and displacement with a subsurf modifier but that just makes the whole model super distorted and weird for some reason(not due to the subsurf). I cant upload the new blend packaged file due to some error on blend exchange I'm sorry but here's a link to the free material that im using if thats any help: https://ambientcg.com/view?id=Plastic006 (I've got the 4k version)

Comment: in that case please use another platform like workupload.com

Comment: @moonboots I've done it! let me know if theres any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to select *Displacement Only* or *Displacement and Bump* in the *Material* settings:

[image]

Also you need to subdivide your object, otherwise the *Displacement* node won't have anything to displace (a *Subdivision Surface* modifier won't work as it won't subdivide homogeneously):

[image]

At last make sure that your unwrap is correct, here as you can see the part I was highlighting has too many islands, it may create weird separations in the displacement, maybe unwrap again (with the *Follow Active Quads* mode for example):

[image]

Instead of the *Displacement* node you could also try the *Displace* modifier that may be simpler (or just fake the displacement with a *Bump* node).

Comment: hello, thank you very much for the help! I added subdivisions using loop cuts and tried setting the displacement setting to "displacement and bump" however im still super new to blender so I don't really know how to work with the UV editor just yet so I skipped that step for now. however even then the object became extremely distorted(spikes coming out of everywhere) once I connected the displacement node so I tried plugging it into bump instead and it looks pretty ok for now! ill stick with this until I figure out the UV editor, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure why it is extremely distorted, but if you want to unwrapwith the Follow Active Quads options you just need to select all your mesh in Edit mode, shift select one square face, unwrap and the mesh will unwrap orthogonally.